# Base for grippers?

Tags: ros, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i'm currently developing a driver for a gripper. Or let's say.. I'm starting to develop... ;)

Anyway i was looking for a existing driver and found the WubbleGripper and PR2_gripper_action.
I'll have a look at them, but i'm wondering why there isn't anything in the driver section mentioned about grippers.
In my opinion grippers are probably quite essential in robotics and would be good to have some existing messages/services/actions i could build my stuff on.

Are grippers just too different to have a common base? or what's the reason why there isn't anything?

cheers
Mimax

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11657/base-for-grippers?/) by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2011-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to have a look at the [GraspHandPostureExecutionAction](http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_manipulation_msgs/GraspHandPostureExecutionAction). Of course whether that is the right choice for you depends on what you want; my reason for choosing this action format for our gripper is that the [object_manipulator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_manipulator) needs it.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1